# String tokenise an xpath expression

Tags: c, xpath, strtok, strsep

I have below program to tokenise an Xpath expression. But it cannot handle expressions like this one:

```
/employees/employee[secret-code=a/b/c][unicode=d/e/f]/salary
```

Basically tokenizing by '/' breaks since the predicates themselves contain '/'.

```
const char *g_xpath_node_delim = "/";

static void tokenize_xpath (char *xpath_str)
{
    const char *tok = NULL;

    if (!xpath_str)
        return;

    while ((tok = strsep(&xpath_str, g_xpath_node_delim)) != NULL) {
        
        if (tok[0] == '\0')
            continue;
        fprintf(stdout, "\nToken '%s'\n", tok);
    }
}
```

I want to construct a structure of nodes along with their predicates. Any hints?

Comment: strsep is a simplistic tool not suitable for breaking down complex expressions. You need a parser.

Comment: And `strtok()` and its relatives are even worse than `strsep()`.  You need to identify the separator and CC allow for `[` as well as `/`.  Look at `strcspn()`.

Comment: Is `a/b/c` an xpath too or just a value? As it is now it's an xpath probably relative to `employee`. if it's a value it should be quoted and not tokenized I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath has a fairly complex grammar (I won't go into any computer science for classes of grammar, because I'm hazy on the subject myself) but it's a recursively-defined grammar which means you can't do proper analysis of expression structure with a single-level regex-based tokenizer. You'll need a real XPath parser to build a syntax tree. Depending on what you want to achieve and how much effort you want to put in, you can either try to take advantage of an existing open-source XPath parser, or write your own.